# Showing the line numbers in <pre> in Django project using Pygments

Tags: javascript, python, css, django, pygments

I'm using the [Pygments](https://pygments.org/) package in my Django project. When I try to render the code snippet in my template, it renders the whole data as follows:

###### Template:

```html
...
{% pygmentify %}
<pre class="{{snippet.lang}}">{{snippet.body}}</pre>
{% endpygmentify %}
...
```

##### Final rendered HTML:

```html
<pre lang="python">
...
<span class="kn">import</span> <span class="nn">hello</span>
<span class="nb">print</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="s1">'hey'</span><span class="p">)</span>
<span class="k">def</span> <span class="nf">test</span><span class="p">():</span>
<span class="nb">print</span><span class="p">(</span><span class="s1">'in the function'</span><span class="p">)</span>
...
</pre>
```

It actually works with no pain. The entire code block is being highlighted properly. The thing is that I want to show the line number as well. Should I style them or there is only a simple Pygments configuration needed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using django-pygmentify, you can pass keyword arguments as indicated in [their docs](https://django-pygmentify.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#customize-with-keyword-arguments)

```
{% pygmentify linenos='inline' %}
<pre class="{{snippet.lang}}">{{snippet.body}}</pre>
{% endpygmentify %}
```

Comment: It kinda worked but the whole style of the code block is completely chalked! Is it ok to style the line number sidebar? It's like this keyword converts the [pre-code] style to a table!! I don't get it.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by chalked, but you can pass other keywords for a specific style or css file, as shown in the docs link. There are a number of options you can tweak.

Comment: @Alireza Try the new code. `'inline'` will integrate it to the <pre> tag, while all other `linenos` values make a table.

Comment: That's it. Thanks. Any way to set a style for these <pre>s? (I know I can access them by using inner CSS selectors btw)

Comment: Just explore the link in my answer and the link it has to HTMLFormatter. I think the `style` keyword argument might be relevant, but I haven't personally used it enough to give you a direct answer

Comment: Enough assists I think. Much obliged.